# Is the following a measure on $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}\cap \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) )$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\gamma: \mathbb{Q}\cap \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \{0,1\}$
be given by
$$
\gamma(A) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }A\text{ is countable}\\
1 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

I think it is true because any subset $A\subset \mathbb{Q}\cap \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ will be countable (as it is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$) and therefore the function is identically zero (which is obviously a measure).
But the solutions manual says that

> On Q (and, actually, any possible -algebra thereon) the problem is totally different: if  is countable, then $A^c$ = Q ⧵  is also countable and vice versa. This means that () is, according to the definition, both 1 and 0 which is, of course, impossible. This is to say:  is not well-defined.  makes only sense on a non-countable set .

Is their argument correct? How can we have an uncountable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ so that $\gamma(A) = 1$? This is exercise 4.3 from Measures, Integrals, and Martingales by Schilling.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but every subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: @Batominovski So $\gamma(A) = 0$ for all subsets and so its a measure?

Comment: I think you are right. $\gamma$ is by definition the zero-map on each subset of $\mathbb Q$, especially $\gamma(\mathbb Q)=0$. That is a trivial measure.

Comment: The argument which you are refering works on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, because $\gamma(\mathbb R)=1$, $\gamma((-\infty,0))=1$ and $\gamma([0,\infty))=1$ but $$1=\gamma(\mathbb R)=\gamma((-\infty,0)\cup[0,\infty))=\gamma((-\infty,0))+\gamma([0,\infty))=1+1=2$$

Comment: @MundronSchmidt yeah that's what I did on the first part and he has that as the solution to the first part. not sure why he wrote the above for the second part though. a typo i guess? http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/solutions-mims-2ed.pdf

Comment: I suppose it is a mistake. That can happen.